# Azure Data Factory: security for Web and Webhook activities

Tags: azure, networking, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, azure-security

I want to integrate ADF pipeline and Nifi flow through ADF's [Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) and [Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity) activities. Means ADF trigger Nifi through HTTP call, than wait till Nifi respond to HTTP hook.
Nifi is deployed on Azure VMs as Docker container.

As far as I know, Azure Data Factory (ADF) has only public endpoint and doesn't have firewall.

*Is there any secure way to arrange HTTP communication between ADF and Nifi?*

Important: I'm not passing sensitive data between ADF and Nifi, only pipeline arguments. But I want to make sure that nobody except Nifi can trigger ADF Webhook. And nobody except ADF may trigger Nifi HTTP listener.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can call a API from ADF is by using web activity , unfortunately web activity can only access url on public domain . I don't think you can use ADF for this .

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17779

Comment: the way I'm going to dela with this - call public facing Api Gateway with SSL certificate, then call private network machines after SSL termination